# Java processing lines in file and data structures

Tags: java, arrays, regex, database, hash

I have read a bit about multidimensional arrays would it make sense to solve this problem using such data structures in Java, or how should I proceed?

Problem

1. I have a text file containing records which contain multiple lines. One record is anything between `<SUBBEGIN` and `<SUBEND`.
2. The lines in the record follow no predefined order and may be absent from a record. In the input file (see below) I am only interested in lines `MSISDN`, `CB`,`CF` and `ODBIC` fields.
3. For each of these fields I would like to apply regular expressions to extract the value to the right of the equals.
4. Output file would be a comma separated file containing these values, example 
   `MSISDN=431234567893` the value `431234567893` is written to the output file
5. error checking

   `NoMSISDNnofound`  when no `MSISDN` is found in a record

   `noCFUALLPROVNONE` when no `CFU-ALL-PROV-NONE` is found in a recored
6. Search and replace operations

   `CFU-ALL-PROV-NONE` should be replaced by `CFU-ALL-PROV-1/1/1`

   `CFU-TS10-ACT-914369223311` should be replaced by `CFU-TS10-ACT-1/1/0/4369223311`

Output for first record

`431234567893,BAOC-ALL-PROV,BOIC-ALL-PROV,BOICEXHC-ALL-PROV,BICROAM-ALL-PROV,CFU-ALL-PROV-1/1/1,CFB-ALL-PROV-1/1/1,CFNRY-ALL-PROV-1/1/1,CFNRY-ALL-PROV-1/1/1,CFU-TS10-ACT-1/1/1/4369223311,BAIC,BAOC`

Input file

```
<BEGINFILE>
    <SUBBEGIN
    IMSI=11111111111111;
    MSISDN=431234567893;
    CB=BAOC-ALL-PROV;
    CB=BOIC-ALL-PROV;
    CB=BOICEXHC-ALL-PROV;
    CB=BICROAM-ALL-PROV;
    IMEISV=4565676567576576;
    CW=CW-ALL-PROV;
    CF=CFU-ALL-PROV-NONE-YES-NO-NONE-YES-65535-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO;
    CF=CFB-ALL-PROV-NONE-YES-YES-NONE-YES-65535-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO;
    CF=CFNRY-ALL-PROV-NONE-YES-YES-NONE-YES-65535-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO;
    CF=CFNRC-ALL-PROV-NONE-YES-NO-NONE-YES-65535-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO;
    CF=CFU-TS10-ACT-914369223311-YES-YES-25-YES-65535-YES-YES-NO-NO-NO-YES-YES-
    YES-YES-NO;    
    ODBIC=BAIC;
    ODBOC=BAOC;
    ODBROAM=ODBOHC;
    ODBPRC=ENTER;
    ODBPRC=INFO;
    ODBPLMN=NONE;
    ODBPOS=NOBPOS-BOTH;
    ODBECT=OdbAllECT;
    ODBDECT=YES;
    ODBMECT=YES;
    ODBPREMSMS=YES;
    ODBADULTSMS=YES;
    <SUBEND
    <SUBBEGIN
    IMSI=11111111111133;
    MSISDN=431234567899;
    CB=BAOC-ALL-PROV;
    CB=BOIC-ALL-PROV;
    CB=BOICEXHC-ALL-PROV;
    CB=BICROAM-ALL-PROV;
    CW=CW-ALL-PROV;
    CF=CFU-ALL-PROV-NONE-YES-NO-NONE-YES-65535-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO+-NO-NO;
    CF=CFB-ALL-PROV-NONE-YES-YES-NONE-YES-65535-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO;
    CF=CFNRY-ALL-PROV-NONE-YES-YES-NONE-YES-65535-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO;
    CF=CFNRC-ALL-PROV-NONE-YES-NO-NONE-YES-65535-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO;
    CF=CFU-TS10-ACT-914369223311-YES-NO-NONE-YES-65535-YES-YES-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO-NO;
    CF=CFD-TS10-REG-91430000000-YES-YES-25-YES-65535-YES-YES-NO-NO-NO-YES-YES-YES-YES-NO;
    ODBIC=BICCROSSDOMESTIC;
    ODBOC=BAOC;
    ODBROAM=ODBOH;
    ODBPRC=INFO;
    ODBPLMN=PLMN1
    ODBPLMN=PLMN3;
    ODBPOS=NOBPOS-BOTH;
    ODBECT=OdbAllECT;
    ODBDECT=YES;
    ODBMECT=YES;
    ODBPREMSMS=NO;
    ODBADULTSMS=YES;
    <SUBEND
```

Comment: Please (re)format your question. As it stands, it's a) hard to read and b) difficult to comprehend what you are looking for.

Comment: Please post a concise, actual question and illustrative what you have already done to try and solve the problem, with code.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you are simply reading a text file and processing it and maybe replacing some words. You do not therefore need a data structure to store the words in. Instead you can simply read the file line by line and pass it through a bunch of if statements (maybe a couple booleans to check if the specific parameters you are searching for have been found?) and then rewrite the line you want to a new file.

Answer (score 2):

Dealing with big files to implement data in machine learning algorithms, I did it by passing all of the file contents in a variable, and then using the String.split("delimeter") method (Supported from Java 8 and later), I broke the contents in a one-dimensional array, where each cell had the info before the delimeter.

Firstly read the file via a scanner or your way of doing it (let content be the variable with your info), and then break it with
`content.split("<SUBEND");`